# Akka Supervisor Strategy for Router

Tags: akka

I am very new to Akka and I had the following question:

I have a MasterActor where a router is defined and that is where I defined the supervisionStrategy:

```
override val supervisorStrategy =  OneForOneStrategy() {
case _: FileNotFoundException => 
println("******  Failed actor in FileNotFound: " + sender)
Restart
}
```

I then passed this supervisionStrategy to the router:

```
val router = context.actorOf(RemoteRouterConfig(RoundRobinPool(3,   supervisorStrategy=supervisorStrategy), addresses).props(Props(classOf[MapActor], reduceActor)), "router")
```

I placed a print statement in the postRestart method and I see that only one actor is restarted.  This led me to believe that I was on the right track.

However, I have 2 issues so far:

Issue #1:

I noticed that sender is deadLetters in the print statement.  I expected it to be the failed actor.

Issue #2:

I put a print statement in the postRestart method and I saw that only one routee is restarted when a FileNotFound exception is encountered and the processing of the continues.  That seems like the correct behavior.

However, if I change the supervisorStrategy to Stop on the FileNotFound exception, (shown below), I see that ALL actors stop and I do not ANY processing taking place, at all.  I expected to see processing occur by all actors until one encounters a FileNotFound exception.   When the failed actor hits the FileNotFound exception, I thought that ONLY that actor should be stopped and the others should continue processing.

```
override val supervisorStrategy =  OneForOneStrategy() {
case _: FileNotFoundException => 
println("******  Failed actor in FileNotFound: " + sender)
Stop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to issue #1: this is expected. The `sender()` you're calling here is the one in the context of your `MasterActor`. It is only allowed to call this method during message processing, so behavior in this example is undefined. (The reference to `deadLetters` here is confusing, this has been improved in version 2.5.1 of Akka)

With respect to issue #2 I'm not quite sure, I suspect it has to do with the fact that you're wrapping the `RoundRobinPool` in a `RemoteRouterConfig` but I'm not that familiar with that part of the system.